# How to return pagination with django framework?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How to return pagination with django framework?

I'm trying to use the class LimitOffsetPagination.

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you guys

```
class Sellers(APIView):
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination

    def get(self, request):

    transactions = Transactions.objects.all()


        page = self.paginate_queryset(transactions, request)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(transactions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)





page = self.paginate_queryset(transactions, request)
AttributeError: 'Sellers' object has no attribute 'paginate_queryset'
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think APIView has `pagination` support. You need to use [**`GenericAPIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview):

```
class Sellers(GenericAPIView):
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination

    def get(self, request):
        transactions = Transactions.objects.all()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(transactions)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = YourSerializer(transactions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Or more simply use [**`ListAPIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) where django rest framework handles everything for you:

```
class Sellers(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = YourSerializer # you need to define a serializer and put it here
    queryset = Transactions.objects.all()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.get('offset', None) and self.request.GET.get('limit', None):
           self._paginator = LimitOffsetPagination
        else:
           self._paginator = PageNumberPagination
        return super(Sellers, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Transactions.objects.filter(user=self.request.session['user_id'])
 
    # You don't need to override the `.get()` method
```

Comment: Thanks for listening ruddra. I will see what you have proposed. With APIView not working?

Comment: you are calling `self.paginate_queryset(...)`, as far as I see [**`APIView`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/908516f2bdec997238be912918b74ae2891ff948/rest_framework/views.py#L104) does not have any method named `paginate_queryset`. But `GenericAPIView` has it.

Comment: With ListAPIView AssertionError: 'Sellers' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add it. Please see my updated answer

Comment: THANK you Ruddra.  Can you tell if you can use ps LimitOffsetPagination and PageNumberPagination together? PageNumberPagination does page count?

Comment: @marcelo.delta please see my updated answer. hope it helps

Comment: @marcelo.delta in my latest update, I have provided usage of both `LimitOffsetPagination` and `PageNumberPagination` pagination methods.

Comment: Thank you so muth. Error is the result - return self.get_pagination_class().paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
TypeError: paginate_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: Same error. return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
TypeError: paginate_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: Can you please share the full code stacktrace in the question? thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of generic `ListAPIView`. You can use built-in functionality to speedup the development like below.

```
class Sellers(ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    queryset = Transactions.objects.all()
```

Reference: 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview

Answer (score 0):

Editing Ruddura's second answer, using `self.pagination_class` instead of `self._paginator` because it throws some strange errors.

Edited answer:

```
class Sellers(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = YourSerializer # you need to define a serializer and put it here
    queryset = Transactions.objects.all()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.get('offset', None) and self.request.GET.get('limit', None):
           self.pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
        else:
           self.pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
        return super(Sellers, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Transactions.objects.filter(user=request.session['user_id'])

     # ...
     return self.get_paginated_response(self.paginate_queryset(serializer.data))
```

AND in settings.py add:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   # ...
   'PAGE_SIZE': 100 //Change to preference
   # ...
 }
```